# Cannot get Fragment to show

Tags: android, android-fragments

Trying to create a bottom navigation bar using 3 fragments. Followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPV8xA7m-iw  which worked fine but I could not get it to switch from fragment to fragment. It doesn't even start with the initial fragment.

As you will notice, I set up print statements to see if it actually registered the button clicks, and it prints it but does not activate the fragment

```
    package com.starenkysoftware.macapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //webView.loadUrl("https://calendar_layout.google.com/calendar_layout/htmlembed?src=wlmacci@gmail.com&ctz=America/Toronto&dates=20190401/20190501");

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new CalendarFragment()).commit();
}

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment=null;

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_calander:
                            selectedFragment = new CalendarFragment();
                            System.out.println("1");
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_announcements:
                            selectedFragment = new AnnouncementsFragment();
                            System.out.println("2");
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_late_starts:
                            selectedFragment = new LateStartsFragment();
                            System.out.println("3");
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };
}
```

here is the calendar_layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Calendar Fragment"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.starenkysoftware.macapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas? Help is very appreciated

Comment: Could you paste your layout xml?

Comment: please post xml , too

Comment: Added both XMLs

Answer (score 0):

You should add fragment first.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new CalendarFragment(), CalendarFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. Replace will work as an add if there there hasn't been any additions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I previously had a WebView but I commented it thinking it wouldn't show up but it was just taking up the screen. Set visibility to invisible, fixed everything